# Find main ant build file of eclipse projects

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

If I have a series of eclipse projects that each have a build.xml file is there a way to figure out the “central” build file for all projects without having to go over each build file one by one?

Comment: I know this is pretty basic and you might have already covered this but just to confirm, do you see a build.xml in the root directory of your workspace where all these projects reside?

Comment: @bot:no there is not one. But I do see a project that its name hints to be something central that has a .externalToolBuilders